# Extract strings inside double quotes with QRegularExpression

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I have a string like below:

```
on prepareFrame
  go to frame 10
    goToNetPage "http://www.apple.com"
    goToNetPage "http://www.cnn.com"
    etc..
end
```

I want to extract all the urls from this string by using QRegularExpression. I've already tried:

```
QRegularExpression regExp("goToNetPage \"\\w+\"");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = regExp.globalMatch(handler);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    QString handler = match.captured(0);
}
```

But this not working.

Comment: You should use `regExp("goToNetPage\\s*\"[^\"]+\"")`. Or, `regExp("goToNetPage\\s*\"([^\"]+)")` and then access the value in Group 1 using `match.captured(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
QRegExp regExp("goToNetPage\\s*\"([^\"]+)");
QStringList MyList;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = regExp.indexIn(handler, pos)) != -1) {
    MyList << regExp.cap(1);
    pos += regExp.matchedLength();
}
```

The pattern is

```
goToNetPage\s*"([^"]+)
```

It matches `goToNetPage`, 0 or more whitespace chars, `"` and then captures into Group 1 any 1+ chars other than `"` - the required value is accessed  using `regExp.cap(1)`.